# Testing whether functions passed through function parameters are getting called (Android/Kotlin))

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin, mockito

Is there any way to check whether a function passed through another function's parameter is getting called? For example,

```
override fun updateWeight(value: Editable,
                          showEmptyError: () -> Unit,
                          showOutOfRangeError: () -> Unit,
                          dismissAlertDialog: () -> Unit,
                          updateAndShow: (Float) -> Unit) {
    if (value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        showEmptyError()
    } else {
        val floatVal = value.toString().trim().toFloat()
        if (floatVal > 300) {
            showOutOfRangeError()
        } else {
            dismissAlertDialog()
            updateAndShow(floatVal)
        }
    }
}
```

I need to test above method with different values for `value` parameter and check which method is executing? I tried searching for an answer but I couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: are you in control of passing the corresponding functions into the updateWeight in your test?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 Yes. I'm doing an app with MVP architecture and this is a presenter function. This method is called from an Activity with needed parameters.

Comment: You could pass lambdas that set some state for your test which you can check afterward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168588/kotlin-unit-testing-a-function-that-takes-a-function-as-parameter/49168760#49168760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mock lambda functions using `Mockito`. For example `showEmptyError` test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class TestUpdateWeight {
    @Mock
    lateinit var showEmptyError: () -> Unit
    @Mock
    lateinit var showOutOfRangeError: () -> Unit
    @Mock
    lateinit var dismissAlertDialog: () -> Unit
    @Mock
    lateinit var updateAndShow: (Float) -> Unit

    @Test
    fun testShowEmptyErorr() {
        updateWeight("", showEmptyError, showOutOfRangeError, dismissAlertDialog, updateAndShow)

        verify(showEmptyError).invoke()
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(showOutOfRangeError)
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(dismissAlertDialog)
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(updateAndShow)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property showEmptyError has not been initialized` comes up

Comment: Have you added @Mock annotation to this property?

Comment: It worked. I forgot to add the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)` above the class

Answer (score 0):

You can just log value with different tag
like for `showEmptyError` method you can log

```
Log.d("showEmptyError value",value.toString()) // inside your showEmptyError() method
```

same as different method use different tag which first parameter in `Log.d`
and your result will be print in Logcat.

But to do this you should have to accept value parameter in showEmptyError. So prototype should be `showEmptyError(value:Editable)`